# An Issue with converting enumerations in C++\CLI

Tags: c#, enums, c++-cli, enumeration

I have an assembly, written in C++\CLI, which uses some of enumerations, provided by .Net. It has such kind of properties:

```
property System::ServiceProcess::ServiceControllerStatus ^ Status  
{  
    ServiceControllerStatus ^ get()  
    {  
        return (ServiceControllerStatus)_status->dwCurrentState;   
    }  
}
```

it works fine, but when i use this assembly from my C# code, type of this property is

```
System.Enum
```

and i have to make type-cast

```
 if ((ServiceControllerStatus)currentService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
     //do smth
```

The question is simple: why is it so, and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++/CLI **^** is like the analagous * in standard C++. Because enumerations are value types the **^** should not be included otherwise you will see them as **System.Enum**.

Remove the ^ and you will see the correct enumeration on C# side.

```
property System::ServiceProcess::ServiceControllerStatus Status  
{  
    System::ServiceProcess::ServiceControllerStatus get()  
    {  
        return (System::ServiceProcess::ServiceControllerStatus)_status->dwCurrentState;   
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think enums don't use the ^ -- try removing it from the property declaration and get().